# Can a MonoBehaviour be a private inner class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use a private inner class `MonoBehaviour` as part of the internal implementation of a class (also a `MonoBehaviour`). Reduced to the essentials:

```
public class OuterClass : MonoBehaviour {
  public void SomeMethod(GameObject go) {
    go.AddComponent<InnerClass>();
  }

  private class InnerClass : MonoBehaviour {
  }
}
```

**This appears to be all working absolutely fine, with no errors or warnings.** But it also appears to violate the statement in the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html) that:

> The class name and file name must be the same to enable the script
> component to be attached to a GameObject.

Is this a problematic violation of that rule? If so, what are the problems? I am aware that it means the script is not visible in the Editor, but that's exactly what I want: it should never be added by anything other than its enclosing class.

Comment: That component cannot be added to a gameobject, period.  Therefore it doesnt really make any sense to make it private.  Did you try adding the component to an object yet?

Comment: @hijinxbassist Yes, just like in the example code - from a method of the outer class - and it works just fine.

Comment: Oh wow.. I have never tried that, but assumed it would fail due to not being named the same as the file.  I would be hesitant because that "loophole" may close in the future, but if it works maybe they will update their docs with an official support of that scenario.

Comment: I interpret the "must" in the documentation to mean "must, if you want to be able to add the component via the Add Component button in the inspector", since that's what their users want to do 99.999% of the time. It doesn't impact the underlying semantics of the language in the game runtime though.

Comment: Interesting usecase. It definitely breaks with the "convention" and the Editor as you say ... but .. well ... if it works it works ^^ The question however: **When/Why would you ever need this?** The whole purpose of a `MonoBehaviour` (component) is that it is A) attached to a specific `GameObject` (fulfilled by you) and B) that other components can access it via `GetComponent` (not fulfilled by you) ... if this is not the case why not simply make it a totally normal non-MonoBehaviour private class, have an instance and call `Update` etc "manually" from the surrounding `MonoBehaviour` ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but you can't add it in the editor. Unity might not see it, but since it's still a monobehavior, you can add it to a gameobject through code and it will work just fine.